# Hide with Media Queries & Isotope

Tags: jquery, hide, media-queries, jquery-isotope

I'm building a responsive web with Isotope for the "masonry" type of layout. However when I set `display: none` with a media query to a Isotope-item the dimensions stays intact making it still take up its space. Guess there must be an easy solution for this I just can't see?

Comment: the key for solution is code .. and you dont have any ! please post some code so people could help beter . or even create a jsfiddle so we can see and work on the problem together .!

Comment: Is your aim to hide isotope items with media queries or just change their size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my fuzzy question. I found out that as soon as you turn an element into a isotope-item it will take up its space even if `display: none` is set. The solution in my case was to simply add `width: 0; height= 0`.